# running java class from jar in coldfusion - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, coldfusion, coldfusion-11

I am completely stuck on this.  I don't understand cold fusion enough and cant find an answer to this to know whats going wrong.

Here is the portion of my coldfusion script that is the problem, using generic names for things here

```
<cfscript>
    function run() {

        var obj = createObject("java", "com.company.Run");

        var variable1= "string1";
        var variable2= "string2";
        var variable3= "string3";

        obj.init();

        var success = obj.runThis(variable1, variable2, variable3); <-- failing here
        return success;
    }
</cfscript>
<cfset success = run()>
<cfoutput>SUCCESS? #success#</cfoutput>
```

The java code that this accessed is in a jar, which is compiled and works for simple methods inside that class.  for example, i can do this, using the java code below the coldfusion script and it works without a single problem:

```
<cfscript>
    function run() {

        var obj = createObject("java", "com.company.Run");

        var variable= "string";

        obj.init();

        var success = obj.print(variable); <-- failing here
        return success;
    }
</cfscript>
<cfset success = run()>
<cfoutput>SUCCESS? #success#</cfoutput>


public static String print(String input) {
    return input;
}
```

What I am trying to get running is my first cold fusion script above with this sort of idea, inside this class it is running "runThis" which constructs an object from another class and then runs a method from that object which returns a string.  These are both in the same jar so should all be accessible and run fine when I run just junit tests against the exact same code.  the issue here is pulling it into coldfusion and running it there:

```
public class Run {
public Run() {

    }
public String runThis(String variable1, String variable1, String variable3) throws Exception {

        try {
            MyObject object= new MyObject (variable1, variable2, variable3);
            return object.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "error";
        }
    }
}
```

the error I am receiving:

```
"Error","http-bio-8500-exec-7","10/08/14","10:47:13",,"javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException The specific sequence of files included or processed is: C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\company\response.cfm, line: 77 "
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/ws/rs/WebApplicationException
    at com.company.Run.runThis(Run.java:21)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at coldfusion.runtime.java.JavaProxy.invoke(JavaProxy.java:97)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invoke(CfJspPage.java:2483)
    at cfresponse2ecfm1522673216$funcRUN.runFunction(C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\company\response.cfm:77)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:487)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod$ArgumentCollectionFilter.invoke(UDFMethod.java:383)
    at coldfusion.filter.FunctionAccessFilter.invoke(FunctionAccessFilter.java:95)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.runFilterChain(UDFMethod.java:334)
    at coldfusion.runtime.UDFMethod.invoke(UDFMethod.java:231)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage._invokeUDF(CfJspPage.java:2840)
    at cfresponse2ecfm1522673216.runPage(C:\ColdFusion11\cfusion\wwwroot\company\response.cfm:82)
    at coldfusion.runtime.CfJspPage.invoke(CfJspPage.java:246)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.handlePageInvoke(IncludeTag.java:734)
    at coldfusion.tagext.lang.IncludeTag.doStartTag(IncludeTag.java:570)
    at coldfusion.filter.CfincludeFilter.invoke(CfincludeFilter.java:65)
    at coldfusion.filter.IpFilter.invoke(IpFilter.java:45)
    at coldfusion.filter.ApplicationFilter.invoke(ApplicationFilter.java:487)
    at coldfusion.filter.RequestMonitorFilter.invoke(RequestMonitorFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.filter.MonitoringFilter.invoke(MonitoringFilter.java:40)
    at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:141)
    at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
    at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
    at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:58)
    at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
    at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
    at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
    at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:219)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at coldfusion.inspect.weinre.MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.doFilter(MobileDeviceDomInspectionFilter.java:121)
    at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:422)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:313)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1718)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1569)
    ... 56 more
```

I have a feeling that I am not instantiating the MyObject object correctly or that this is where the code is failing.  Removing that seems to allow the code to work, but obviously will not get me what I am going for.

Comment: Aside from `com.company.*`, what other packages does your custom jar contain? The exception references `javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException` which I *believe* is already included as one of CF's core jars. Is that included in your custom jar? *Might* be a conflict.. Hard to say though as I see both NoClassDefFoundError and ClassNotFoundException in the trace :/

Comment: not including that directly in my class, but good idea to check

Comment: Any other external packages in the jar aside from `com.company.*` ? Also are you able to successfully create and instance of that class from CF and dump it? ie `test = createObject("java", "javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException"); writeDump(test);`

Comment: I was wrong, checked and I am importing javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException, removed it and I have a new error pointing at a custom error exception.  seeing if i can get around using that too.

Comment: as i remove unnecessary code i am finding its looking for new jars, i believe my issue is that i have not included the jars needed in my custom class to run its code.  working on fixing this now.

Comment: that was it, I had some missing jars, works now!  thank you for the help, post this as an answer and i will mark as the answer on this question.

Comment: Just saw your comment.  Done. I was creating an example to demonstrate, so I included that as well. Even though you already solved the problem, it might be helpful for the next guy :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I strongly suspect your jar is missing one or more dependencies.

I do not have access to CF11 at the moment, but you can reproduce a similar trace by exporting a project to a jar, BUT omitting some of the required classes. For example, I created dummy versions of your two classes (see below). Notice `MyObject` references a *third* class - `YetAnotherClass`. I then exported everything to a jar, but deliberately excluded `YetAnotherClass`.

Using your test code, I can successfully invoke `print()`. However, when the code invokes `runThis()` a similar error occurs. A `NoClassDefFoundError`, caused by `ClassNotFoundException` - because I neglected to include it in the jar.

*Note, I am testing with CF10.*

**CF Code**

```
<cfscript>
    obj = createObject("java", "com.company.Run");
    result = obj.print("testing...");
    writeDump(result);

    obj.init();
    result = obj.runThis("john", "doe", "atlanta");
    writeDump(result);
</cfscript>
```

**Error Stack Trace:**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/othercompany/YetAnotherClass
    at com.company.MyObject.<init>(MyObject.java:10)
    at com.company.Run.runThis(Run.java:9)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    ......
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.othercompany.YetAnotherClass
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1688)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1533)
```

**Run**

```
package com.company;

public class Run {

    public Run() {
    }

    public String runThis(String var1, String var2, String var3) throws Exception {
        MyObject object= new MyObject(var1, var2, var3);
        return object.execute();
    }

    public static String print(String input) {
        return input;
    }
}
```

**MyObject**

```
package com.company;

import java.util.Date;
import com.othercompany.YetAnotherClass;

public class MyObject {

    private YetAnotherClass other;
    public MyObject(String first, String last, String city) {
        this.other = new YetAnotherClass();
    }

    public String execute() {
        return "Method execute invoked at "+ new Date();
    }
}
```

**YetAnotherClass** (different package)

```
package com.othercompany;

public class YetAnotherClass {

    public YetAnotherClass() {
        // do nothing to keep it simple
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do these sort of Java integrations is to start with instantiation. So first run your create code and dump the result... what do you see?

```
<cfset obj = createObject("java", "com.company.Run")/>
<cfdump var="#obj#"/>
```

Next dump the init() function (which I do not see in your class but is perhaps part of the superclass):

```
<cfset obj = obj.init()/> // assuming it returns an instance of Run
<cfdump var="#obj#"/>
```

What's the dump show you? You should definitely see runThis as a method to the class.

Finally work through the runThis method. Keep in mind that the variables you pass must be Java String Types - that's probably your issue. If they aren't the right type then the args are calling a different method signature. Instead of a helpful message like, "I have a runThis but those are not the right arguments or types" Java simply throws "method not found" (because you can overlaod a method by passing in different args).

If it is a problem with the string type try using JavaCast() in your method call as in:

```
var variable1= Javacast("String","string1");
```

Setting the type in this way usually allows your data to be marshalled accross the threshold between Java and CF as the correct type.

This post on [Java and CF](http://www.coldfusionmuse.com/index.cfm/2009/2/23/Unpacking-Java-In-Coldfusion) is somewhat dated but it has a few useful approaches in it.

Hope this helps.

Comment: (Edit) These are all good troubleshooting steps, but I do not know if lack of javacast is the issue. Assuming that is the full trace, the exceptions *suggest* there is a more fundamental problem instantiating the `MyObject` class, like dependency on a missing class or a possible version conflict that manifests itself when trying to instantiate another class. Those are complete guesses though, since I don't know exactly how the custom classes are coded or what they are actually doing ... :)

Comment: Thank you.  I tried casting all my values to string susing javacast and it doesnt seem to have solved the problem.

Comment: I will see what i can post, its about 400 lines of code and a lot is proprietary to the company i work for so cannot share everything.

Comment: Leigh, I get what you are saying... but why would he be able to use the obj.print() ... which is part of the superclass eh? and not use runThis() which is a part of the subclass? If he had such a class conflict wouldn't it show up no matter what he called? maybe not...

Comment: @wondergoat77-  Well usually (though not always) NoClassDef or ClassNotFound errors indicate a version conflict or a missing dependency. So the answer the to the earlier question: "Does the jar have any *external* dependencies" ight help decipher what is meant by the `NoClassDef/ClassNotFound` in the trace. If not, the relevant portion of the code is probably the `import`s, any `static` blocks or declarations and the class constructor.

Comment: Hey - try doing it ALL inline... skip the init() like so createobject("java","com.company.Run").runThis(var1, var2, var3);  ... or perhaps WITH the init but still in line as in  createObject(...).init().runThis()

Comment: @MarkAKruger - Well `obj.print` is a static method of `Run`. It seems like the error occurs when he is trying to create an instance of another class ie `MyObject`. If that class had a reference to another class that is  missing or a `static` block that could not complete for some reason, you might not see the error until you try and instantiate `MyObject`- ie invoke `runThis()`. Again, I am just guessing here based on the limited info available ... ;)

Comment: oh... gotcha. So runThis needs other objects while print just returns primitives?

Comment: (Edit) Exactly, it creates instances of *other* classes. Seems like that is when the problem occurs. Plus `Run.print()` is static, so you do not even need to instantiate the `Run` class to use it.

Comment: Yes, I strongly suspect you are missing a dependency. I get the exact same trace (NoClassDefFoundError caused by ClassNotFoundException) with CF10, if I export a project to a jar, but omit some of the class dependencies.

Comment: Leigh - I lost your email address. I have something for you if you will contact me directly.

Comment: @MarkAKruger - Sorry, I did not see your comment. Once multiple people leave comments, I think S.O. only sends notifications when the @ + username syntax is used (excepting the author of course). My email is in my profile, BTW :)

Comment: @leigh Am I blind? I don't see it there.

Comment: No. My bad, I just noticed that field was marked private. I just added it to my profile temporarily. BTW, I submitted a message via your blog. Not sure if it went through.